# Any Examples of D3.brush() used with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, d3

I have a leaflet map that I have placed an SVG "on top of" using the leaflet overlay pane. I want to add a D3 brush to the overlay pane that will then update a separate chart. I've looked around for any examples of simultaneous D3.brush() and leaflet examples but can't seem to find any.

The closest thing I found was this https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1321 and this https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/timeline-scaled-markers/ (this is brushing the chart not the map).

I was wondering if:

1. Anyone knew of any examples, OR
2. Anyone knew if this was possible/reasonably straightforward, OR
3. If possible, anyone had any tips on the sort of issues I might encounter.

Comment: Did you get this working?  Did you find the brush didn't line up with your mouse when in firefox?

Comment: This is an alternative to brush - https://github.com/w8r/leaflet-area-select

Answer (score 2):

I've just made one basic example based on this [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537).

Process

- add your layer group to the map (from GeoJSON)
- save your layer group in a variable, i.e. `var layer_group = L.geoJSON(json, {...}).addTo(your_map);`
- In your `brushended` function, iterate over `layer_group.eachLayer()` and use `your_map.removeLayer(layer)` and `your_map.addLayer(layer)` to control the feature's visibility.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0dyjkk2h/2/

[image: Leaflet map with D3 brush]

Comment: Maybe I did not correctly understand the question. Do you want to be able to brush on the map or on a separate chart (like in my example)?